# Add border BETWEEN cells in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border

I'm trying to display a JTable as a grid, with lines between the cells. I've only been able to add borders within individual cells, though, which never looks correct; if I add full borders, I get a bunch of disconnected boxes, which looks ugly and wrong. Using MatteBorders (as the below code) looks a little better, but results in gaps where border lines don't quite meet.

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    Component stamp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    int top = 1;
    int left = 1;
    int bottom = row == 7 ? 1 : 0; //Grid is always 8x8, this ensures the bottom/right will have full borders.
    int right = column == 7 ? 1 : 0;
    MatteBorder border = new MatteBorder(top, left, bottom, right, Color.BLACK);
    if (stamp instanceof JComponent) {
        ((JComponent) stamp).setBorder(border);
    }
    return stamp;
}
```

I feel like there must be some way to do this properly, so that I just get grid lines between cell elements. What am I missing? If nothing else, is there a way to get MatteBorder to stretch across the gaps, or to push a normal border out slightly further so that the borders of adjacent cells overlap?

EDIT: Got it working with setShowGrid(true) and setGridColor(Color.BLACK).

Comment: You've tried `table.setShowGrid(true);`?

Comment: @whiskeyspider That hadn't been working, but I did some more digging and figured out why - it was just defaulting to the same background color they'd wanted for each individual cell. That + setGridColor() solved it, thanks.

Comment: The default behaviour is to have grid lines between the cells. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: @camickr Yeah, I just realized that I hadn't been seeing them because they had the same color as the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `JTable.setShowGrid(true)` to show default border or use `setShowHorizontalLines(boolean showHorizontalLines)` or `setShowVerticalLines(boolean showVerticalLines)` to show only horizontal or vertical lines

Comment: Just to anyone else reading this: The default margins of JXTreeTable are 0,0, which means the grid is never visible. Use `setRowMargin(1)` and `setColumnMargin(1)` on the table to make them appear.